# Under what conditions might it make better sense to use a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, quadratics

Under what conditions might it make better sense to use a linear function rather than a quadratic or cubic function that fits a few data points more​ closely?
Choose the correct answer below.

- A. When the range of the data is less than the average value of the function.
- B. When the few data points which are fit more closely by the quadratic or cubic function seem inconsistent with the other data.
- C. When the linear function already fits at least 20 data points closely.
- D. When the quadratic or cubic function would change the end behavior of the fit.

Comment: Well, what do you think?

Comment: i think when the rate of change of data is constant it's better to use linear function but I'm confused with the options

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer of this question, it's B
When the few data points which are fit more closely by the quadratic or cubic function seem inconsistent with the other data.
This is for future assistance of others